# Error when uploading a file to GCS bucket using Service Account Impersonation via Curl

Tags: google-cloud-platform, curl, google-cloud-storage

I am impersonating a service account (using access token) and trying to upload an excel file to GCS  bucket using curl. However I am getting a permission error (see below) which is strange because the service account has all the necessary permissions for writing to bucket and I did not give permissions for deleting. Moreover, why would it need delete access when I am trying to upload a file?

I used curl command with XML API which can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#upload-object-xml

For the content type, I used:

```
"Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
```

All I changed was the variables. The error is the following

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>service_account@project_name.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.delete access to the Google Cloud Storage object.</Details></Error>%
```

**Edit**:
even without the `OBJECT_CONTENT_TYPE` flag, the command returns the same error. Out of curiosity, I have tested with a json format and surprisingly it works and I have no idea why. This is the code for json type

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @path_to_myfile/dummy_file.json -H "Authorization: Bearer $GOOGLE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN" "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/my_bucket_name/o?uploadType=media&name=dummy.json"
```

Comment: The delete permission is normal when you override an existing object. There is no update, only create and delete operation on Cloud Storage. Therefore, when an object name already exists and you upload the same name, Cloud Storage delete the old on and create the new one. That's why you need this permission. However, it's the same in XML and in JSON. Are you sure you use the same OAUTH token to perform the same operation?

Comment: Thanks for the info @guillaumeblaquiere . I didn't know about GCS not having "update" operation. I decided to delete all my files in GCS and ran the curl command once again, this time it worked. So I am guessing, somewhere in the bucket, there was a file with same name and since the SA doesn't have the delete permission, it failed to proceed further previously.